# Issue with using guzzle on IIS 7.5 with manually installed PHP 5.6.34 (Thread-safe package)

Tags: php, ssl, configuration, iis-7.5, guzzle

So I have multiple projects using Guzzle for server-side requests, as well as it is used in a few libraries I am using (`Google Adwords PHP library`, for example).

And I have no problem using Guzzle on Mac, but for some reason on windows, it fails. From what I figured out it's usually the PHP application failing (the error event message is below). I assume it's a configuration error, but I am stuck in between `SSL certificates and extensions configuration`.

Maybe someone has run into the issue on `IIS 7.5` and fixed it. Any help is appreciated.

```
Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 5.6.34.0, time stamp: 0x5a975d26
Faulting module name: php5ts.dll, version: 5.6.34.0, time stamp: 0x5a9762c2
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000004105ef
Faulting process id: 0x1900
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3b4cec2c744e1
Faulting application path: E:\_PHP_56_64bit\php-cgi.exe
Faulting module path: E:\_PHP_56_64bit\php5ts.dll
Report Id: 125c6a11-20c2-11e8-8e90-005056c00008
```

Comment: Such crashes can be issues of PHP itself. You have a few options to try: 1) Upgrade PHP, as 5.6 is too old (end of life later this year). 2) Use non thread safe build, which is recommended by both Microsoft and PHP official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Copied from the comment.)

There are several red flags in your question description,

- PHP 5.6. That's a very old release (which will be obsolete soon this year).
- Thread safe package is used. PHP official and Microsoft recommend the non thread safe package.

Thus, by upgrading to the non thread safe package of a more recent PHP release (7.x) you might get the issue resolved.